# opencv-python image processing code-debugging

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I have written a code in OCV-python for image processing(detection of veins in eye), its not working, can somebody help?

```
import os,sys
import numpy as np
import scipy
import cv2
import PIL
import Image
import ImageChops

i=cv2.imread('eye.jpg',0);
cv2.imshow(i);
j= cv2.medianBlur(i, 3);
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8));
k= clahe.apply(j);
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8);
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(k, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);
h, w = i.shape[:2];
seed_pt = None;
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8);
l=cv2.floodFill(k, mask, seed_pt, (255, 255, 255));
o=ImageChops.difference(closing,l);
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(o, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU);
cv2.imshow(im_bw);
```

'

particularly having problem with reading a .jpg file(it reads a .png file), the imshow() function is not working, and errors are being shown for the imagechops and otsu threshold function.

the matlab code for the above code is(it is working perfectly):

```
t=('http://www.ohiolionseyeresearch.com/core/files/uploads/2014/03/1217.png');
 i=imread(t);
 figure, imshow(i)
q=rgb2hsv(i);
t=rgb2gray(i);
figure, imshow(t)
k=medfilt2(t);
figure, imshow(k)
 u=adapthisteq(k);
 se=strel('disk',10);
 c=imclose(u,se);
 figure, imshow(c)
 d=imfill(u,'holes');
 figure, imshow(d)
 z=imabsdiff(c,d);
 figure, imshow(z)
 level=graythresh(z);
 BW=im2bw(z,level);
 imshow(BW)
```

'

Comment: `is not working` is a vague error description. Be specific. What exactly does not work and always include the full traceback of your error.

Comment: Also it is good practice to have self describing variable names and not 'a,b,c,d,e,f,j'. It would make you code easier to read

Comment: semi colons in python ?

Comment: Solve one error at a time... if `imshow` is not working... try to solve by writing a two-line program and posting only relevant code here. Also give some error description.